# Could not load assembly file , System.Text.Json

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have created an SSIS package in VS 2019 to consume an API, doing deserialization using System.Text.Json. It works perfectly when I execute it locally but when I deployed it to SQL Server (SQL Server 2019) and run it as an SQL Job it fails with the error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version 4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken = cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies'.

Where do I have to look for if this file/assembly on the server? or what I need to do to get it to work?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Checked target version of VS and SQL server.

Comment: The server is running what OS? Assembly is likely in the global assembly cache, GAC.